# Unable to find the cause of syntax error

Tags: java

I am new to Java and written simple code:

```
1 package Rndom;
2 class Clmm{
3   
4 }
5 public class Clkk {
6  
7   Clmm klm;
8   klm = new Clmm();
9
10 }
```

Eclipse shows the error:

```
syntax error on token ";" , , expected on line 7
```

I am trying to find why this error is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a variable outside of a method, during it's deceleration. That's why

```
private Clmm klm = new Clmm(); //deceleration and initialization
```

Worked for you.
 However, once it's declared (and initialized, even if it's to a default value) you can only change it's value inside a method or a block. That's why the following code did not work for you:

```
Clmm klm; // deceleration and initialization to default value  
klm = new Clmm(); //assignment, which is a statement that cannot be outside of a block/method
```

Answer (score 4):

put these lines

```
 Clmm klm;
 klm = new Clmm();
```

under

public static void main e.g.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
 Clmm klm;
klm = new Clmm();
}
```

Comment: Or put them in a constructor.

Comment: also rahul didn't mention, `Clkk` is Main class.

Answer (score 2):

Make it `Clmm klm = new Clmm();` like

```
public class Clkk {

   private Clmm klm = new Clmm();

   // getter setter for klm
}
```

Or instantiate `klm` in constructor like :

```
public class Clkk {

   private Clmm klm;
   public Clkk() {
       klm = new Clmm();
   }
   // getter setter for klm
}
```

OR you can have block as

```
public class Clkk {

   private Clmm klm;

   { // this is called block and this is equivalent to constructor. But you can not pass arguments to block. Prefer constructors.
       klm = new Clmm();
   }
   // getter setter for klm
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but if I modify the code like below it doesn't show any error .

    package Rndom;
class Clmm{

}
public class Clkk {
 
 Clmm klm = new Clmm();
}   Just Wondering why....???

Comment: Not sure.. why the error is not displayed in the later case . I just changed  Clmm klm;   klm = new Clmm();.............. to....Clmm klm = new Clmm(); ... could you please explain me the reason why the error is not getting displayed now .

Comment: @rahul : updated answer, you have done it correct, that's why. Why don't you follow some good tutorial? :)

Comment: oo but I was wondering why it was not throwing the error . If you know please suggest me some good links.. so that these kind of issues are ... detailed.. I read.. Herbert shield Complete Refrnce.. n little f Thinking n Java ... but... I guess... I've not.. come across that issue ....Thanks

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ... Thinking in Java, great book by Bruce Eckel! :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put statements outside methods or constructors in the class definition:

```
klm = new Clmm();
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but if I modify the code like below it doesn't show any error .